# Handling multiple top level elements with jq

Tags: json, stream, edit, jq, deluge

I'm trying to modify the `deluge` `web.conf` file with `jq` and I'm having some issues. The deluge web config seems to be invalid json

```
{
  "file": 1,
  "format": 1
}
{
  "sidebar_show_zero": false,
  "show_session_speed": false,
  "pwd_sha1": "CHANGEME",
  "show_sidebar": true,
  "sessions": {},
  "enabled_plugins": [],
  "base": "/",
  "first_login": true,
  "theme": "gray",
  "pkey": "ssl/daemon.pkey",
  "default_daemon": "",
  "cert": "test",
  "session_timeout": 3600,
  "https": false,
  "interface": "0.0.0.0",
  "sidebar_multiple_filters": true,
  "pwd_salt": "salt",
  "port": 8112
}
```

It has multiple top level elements which aren't separated by a comma so if I try to edit the file with `jq` using something like this `jq '.pwd_sha1 = "NEW HASH"' web.conf` I get the following

```
{
  "file": 1,
  "format": 1,
  "pwd_sha1": "NEW HASH"
}
{
  "sidebar_show_zero": false,
  "show_session_speed": false,
  "pwd_sha1": "NEW HASH",
  "show_sidebar": true,
  "sessions": {},
  "enabled_plugins": [],
  "base": "/",
  "first_login": true,
  "theme": "gray",
  "pkey": "ssl/daemon.pkey",
  "default_daemon": "",
  "cert": "test",
  "session_timeout": 3600,
  "https": false,
  "interface": "0.0.0.0",
  "sidebar_multiple_filters": true,
  "pwd_salt": "salt",
  "port": 8112
}
```

`jq` is adding a new element to the first top level object and changing the second top level element's value. How can I get this to only change the existing item in the second top level element?

Comment: `jq 'if has("pwd_sha1") then .pwd_sha1="NEW_HASH" else . end' web.conf`; but why not `deluge-console 'config -s pwd_sha1 "NEW_HASH"'`?

Comment: @Amadan that works but I can't do `deluge-console` since this is a docker image and I'm applying the config in a bash installation script. I could probably use it, but it would be more complicated than just using `jq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web.conf you show is a stream of JSON entities. Fortunately for you, jq is stream-oriented, and it appears from your example that you could simply write:

```
jq 'if .pwd_sha1 then .pwd_sha1 = "NEW HASH" else . end' web.conf
```

In general, though, it might be more appropriate to write something with a more stringent test, e.g.

```
jq 'if type == "object" and has("pwd_sha1") 
  then .pwd_sha1 = "NEW HASH" else . end' web.conf
```

### "changing the second top level element's value"

To edit the second top-level item only, you could use `foreach inputs` with the -n command-line option:

```
foreach inputs as $in (0; .+1; 
  if . == 2 then $in | .pwd_sha1 = "NEW_HASH" 
  else $in end)
```

Comment: this works but you need to change `if .pwd_sha1` to `if has("pwd_sha1")` otherwise it won't match on existing items with a `false` value

Comment: @vane - Did you read the paragraph beginning "In general, though, ..."?

Comment: yes, but even with that, the first statement is still incorrect since it will fail in some cases and you won't know why